# Excel crashing when VBA tries to change the font theme-colour

Tags: vba, fonts

I have a procedure that should check the background colour of a selection of cells, and depending on the colour output a value and then colour the text to match the background.

However, every time this procedure is run, I get the following error. This also causes Excel to freeze, meaning that I have to close and reopen it (simply ending the macro doesn't stop that behavior) -

> Run-time error '-2147417847 (80010108)':
>   Method 'ThemeColor' of object 'Font' failed

Can anyone help me find what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
Private Sub AssignBackgroundValue(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim val As Integer

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Target.Cells

        With c.Interior

            Select Case Target.Interior.ThemeColor
                Case xlThemeColorAccent6
                    val = 1
                Case xlThemeColorAccent5
                    val = 2
                Case xlThemeColorAccent4
                    val = 3
                Case xlThemeColorAccent3
                    val = 4
                Case xlThemeColorAccent2
                    val = 5
                Case xlThemeColorDark1
                    val = 6
                Case xlThemeColorLight1
                    val = 7
            End Select

            c.Font.ThemeColor = IIf(VarType(.ThemeColor) = vbLong, .ThemeColor, 0)
            c.Font.TintAndShade = IIf(VarType(.TintAndShade) = vbDouble, .TintAndShade, 0)

        End With

        c.value = val

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider cases when you are using standard colors and no fill so:

```
Private Sub AssignBackgroundValue(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim val As Integer

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Target.Cells

        With c.Interior
            If IsError(Target.Interior.ThemeColor) Then
                c.Font.PatternTintAndShade = 0
            Else
                Select Case Target.Interior.ThemeColor
                    Case xlThemeColorAccent6
                        val = 1
                    Case xlThemeColorAccent5
                        val = 2
                    Case xlThemeColorAccent4
                        val = 3
                    Case xlThemeColorAccent3
                        val = 4
                    Case xlThemeColorAccent2
                        val = 5
                    Case xlThemeColorDark1
                        val = 6
                    Case xlThemeColorLight1
                        val = 7
                    Case 0
                        val = 0
                End Select

                If val <> 0 Then
                    c.Font.ThemeColor = IIf(VarType(.ThemeColor) = vbLong, .ThemeColor, 0)
                Else
                    c.Font.Color = IIf(VarType(.ThemeColor) = vbLong, .Color, 0)
                End If
                c.Font.TintAndShade = IIf(VarType(.TintAndShade) = vbDouble, .TintAndShade, 0)
            End If
        End With

        c.Value = val
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Good point about checking for non-matches, I've updated to include. I found my issue though, and it was that this procedure was triggered by a change to the Cell, and then it just kept re-firing as I did not disable events (`Application.EnableEvents = False`) for the duration.

Comment: An FYI for anyone else who may come across your answer - `c.Font.TintAndShade` must be set **AFTER** `c.Font.ThemeColor`.